# Finding most common array within an NSObject

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsarray, filtering, nsobject

I have an NSObject "TeamStats" that holds an array of "Possession" objects. The "Possession" objects hold an array of "Players"... For every "Game" there is a "TeamStats" created as well. Two properties on the "Possession" object are didEndInTurnover and didEndInScore. What I need to do is find the most common array of players within a possession that didEndInScore and didEndInTurnover...

What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: Nice chat :P, but did not get the question.

Comment: Are there an unlimited combination of players, or is it likely that a group of players will always be together? In other words, are you looking at players individually, or are you trying to compare something like Line 1 vs Line 2, or Squad A vs Squad B, or something like that where a group of players are always going to be together?

Comment: @GeneralMike yeah that is exactly what I am going for, comparing squad A vs Squad B, but essentially I am trying to compare every squad that appeared during the game object and find the squad the produced the most turnovers... Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, to start, I'd simplify this a little by replacing the array of players with a new NSString variable that just tells what squad that data is for (so you'll have a `NSString *squadName` variable (and you would set `posession1.squadName = @"Squad A"` or something similar) as a property of your `Possession` object, instead of the array of players.  If you want to print out player names or numbers, you could always set up an array or dictionary somewhere else that holds that information for printing to screen - something like

```
NSArray squad1Array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Bill",@"Tom",@"Joe",nil];
NSArray squad2Array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Jim",@"Jeff",@"Mike",nil];
```

Once you have the squads set up, you'll need to loop through the array of `Possession` objects.  In that loop, first check `didEndInTurnover`.  Then you need integer variables for each squad and each `didEndIn...` (so something like `int squadAScore`, `int squadBScore`, `int squadATurnover`, `int squadBTurnover` and so forth).  When you are looping through, check what squad was active for that possession, and increase the integer counter for that squad as appropriate.  Lastly, just compare your integer counters once you have looped through all the possessions to see which one is greatest.

Note that if you wanted to organize this a little better or make it more flexible and less hardcoded, you could probably look into using nested NSDictionaries instead of the integer counters - it would take a bit more work to set up as dictionaries, but if you need to add a new squad later or something, it might be easier to make those kind of changes in the future.

Well, I don't know if any of that is understandable or not.  If it doesn't really make sense, I could try to put some code of what the loop would roughly look like, just let me know.

EDIT: Here's some sample for what the loop is going to look like, using the dictionaries:

```
// Define counters for squads
NSMutableDictionary *turnoverDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *scoreDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

// Loop over all possessions
for (YourPossessionClass *currentPossession in myTeamStats.possessionArry)
{
    if (currentPossession.didEndInTurnover == YES)
    { 
        BOOL found = NO;
        for (NSString *squad in [turnoverDictionary allKeys])
        {
            if ([squad isEqualToString:currentPossession.squad])
            {
                int count = [[turnoverDictionary objectForKey:squad] intValue];
                count ++;
                NSNumber *newCount = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:count];
                [turnoverDictionary setObject:newCount ForKey:squad];
                found = YES;
            }
            //else {Do Nothing - this isn't the squad we want}
        }

        // Add a new entry to the dictionary for this squad if this squad didn't exist before
        if (!found)
        {
            [turnoverDictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:currentPossession.squad];
        }
        //else {Do Nothing - squad was already in dictionary}
    }
    else if {currentPossession.didEndInScore == YES}
    {
        // ... Do all the same stuff as we did for turnover, except now add them to the scoreDictionary instead of the turnoverDictionary ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, although I dont think hard-coding all the NSArrays will work in my case, because there can be an infinite number of squads during a game, for example if 5 players are playing in a game that denotes one squad, if one player subs in for a player on that squad, it becomes a new squad... Does that make sense?

Comment: @Luke: Okay, so in that case you'd have to go to the dictionary method I mentioned in the third paragraph.  That way, you will be able to just tack a new entry into the dictionary when you create a new squad or something.

Comment: @Luke: K, just added the huge code block with what this needs to look like.  I'm assuming here that you're only interested in if it ends in a turnover or a score.  If there are other cases, you will need to add a new dictionary and a new `else if` inside the loop for each.